# How can I get just one result in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Hello I have two tables under a database named people (Info about people)

people
people_tags

I want to get just one result based on id which is a primary key.
The way I tried produced too many results and the info is misleading
as there are 3 or 4 different results repeated.

Many Thanks

Queryy:

```
SELECT 
    people.name,
    people.id,
    mn,
    people_tags.sex,
    people_tags.family
FROM
    people
        RIGHT JOIN
    people_tags ON people.id
WHERE
    people.id = '27';

mysql> select   people.name , people.id, mn , people_tags.sex, people_tags.family  from people RIGHT join people_tags on people.id where people.id = '27';
+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+
| name        | id   | mn   | sex    | family |
+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | ?      | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | Yes    |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Female | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
| Paul Knight |   27 |    6 | Male   | No     |
+-------------+------+------+--------+--------+
78 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My Tables

people

```
    Column      b_year
    Column      date
    Column      id
    Column      mn
    Column      month
    Column      name
    Column      note
    Column      relate
```

people_tags

```
    Column      birthday_tag_id
    Column      deceased
    Column      family
    Column      fam_mem_part
    Column      fam_mem_part_name
    Column      Has_offspring
    Column      id
    Column      Sex
    Column      year_deceased
```

Comment: What happens if you `LEFT JOIN` instead or `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: Which relation ship is between people and people_tags , yor information lacks in deatil so we can#t see the raltionship and can't help

Comment: That being said .. . You're not JOINING **ON** anything .. Try:  `LEFT JOIN people_tags on people.id = people_tags.id`

Comment: Yes that worked, I will have to study it more to understand how it works, many thanks expert..

Comment: mysql> select   people.name , people.id, mn , people_tags.sex, people_tags.family  from people LEFT JOIN people_tags on people.id = people_tags.id where people.id = '27';+-------------+----+------+------+--------+
| name        | id | mn   | sex  | family |
+-------------+----+------+------+--------+
| Paul Knight | 27 |    6 | Male | No     |
+-------------+----+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: The id is in both tables (I think that's the relationship.)

Comment: Too much info or columns to go into one table.

Comment: I just wanted to select certain columns from both tables and have them displayed in one table, I don't know if a join is a right term to use.  Thank's Zac

Comment: I answered your question officially .. If you'd be kind enough to accept it :)

Comment: I was going to upload a screenshot of the result as the table does not display properly on this board. But I don't know how to. Happy it worked

Comment: Thankyou , all sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `LEFT JOIN ON` and bind it by the `id` column in each table.

```
SELECT people.name, 
       people.id, 
       mn , 
       people_tags.sex, 
       people_tags.family  
FROM people 
LEFT JOIN people_tags 
ON people.id = people_tags.id
WHERE people.id = '27';
```